# How to set div tag data to the li tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I am trying to set the div tag data to li tag. For reference, below is the code displayed on doing "inspect". I want to get rid of div tag which contains the class "domTitle".

```
<li style="display: inline;" id="list_name">
    <div class="domTitle">NEWS</div>
    <div class="domDateContainer">RECORDED ON MON JUL 31, 2017
    </div>
</li>
```

But actually, using javascript I want to display something like below code on  doing "inspect":

```
<li style="display: inline;" id="list_name">NEWS
    <div class="domDateContainer">RECORDED ON MON JUL 31, 2017
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Well... if your own code has produce this output - please share...

Comment: If possible it'd be best to change the way the HTML is constructed rather than to fix it afterwards with JS.

Comment: You can use Jquery html() method to get or set html.

Comment: Hi,

I have attached the screen shot of how it displays currently.

Comment: I want to do it by using javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#list_name').text($('#list_name > .domTitle').text());
$('#list_name > .domTitle').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li style="display: inline;" id="list_name">
    <div class="domTitle">NEWS</div>
    <div class="domDateContainer">RECORDED ON MON JUL 31, 2017
    </div>
</li>
```

Solution using jquery

Comment: Thanks, but because of the performance issue, I don't want to use jquery. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that in javascript

```js
function domTitle()
{
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("domTitle")[0];
  var content = ele.innerHTML;
  var parent = document.getElementById("list_name");
  parent.removeChild(ele);
  parent.innerHTML = content + parent.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<li style="display: inline;" id="list_name">
    <div class="domTitle">NEWS</div>
    <div class="domDateContainer">RECORDED ON MON JUL 31, 2017
    </div>
</li>
<button onclick="domTitle()">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var domTitle = $("#list_name > .domTitle").text();
$("#list_name > .domTitle").remove();
$("#list_name").html(domTitle + $("#list_name").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li style="display: inline;" id="list_name">
  <div class="domTitle">NEWS</div>
  <div class="domDateContainer">RECORDED ON MON JUL 31, 2017</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, but because of the performance issue, I don't want to use jquery. :)